# Calling functions with keyboard shortcuts when program is in background

Tags: c#, screenshot

When the program is in the foreground it works, however if it's in background it isn'T working. Help please!

```
private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Control && e.KeyCode.ToString() == "A")
    {
        Bitmap bm = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height);
        Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bm);
        g.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, bm.Size);
        pictureBox1.Image = bm;
    }
}
```

Comment: Also note that people will be upset if you globally take over Ctrl+A ( select all ).  But I'm guessing this is a personal project ... :)

Comment: @Derek - I'd imagine people would get upset for any common shortcut :)

Comment: That is why you should definitely use Ctrl+Shift+LWin+tilde

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow, please take a time to go through the [welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know your way around here (and also to earn your first badge), read how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also check [How to Ask Good Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.